# a lib that loads bmp files on a gnome-based system in C

Tags: c, fedora, gnome, bmp

This is a project that our university is asking us to go through (asking for help on third places is not restricted)
We have to build a 3D scene in which objects are mapped with textures.

I'm stuck where I need to load a BMP file's data into the program.
We have to use a library that is already present in the system (forbidden to code it).

*My request is* :
Using fedora (gnome environment), is there a pre-built library into which a function that loads BMP files and returns a pointer to the payload is existent ?

**EDIT** : We are forbidden to install any additional libs, the lib must be a pre-built lib of Fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the GDK library and the funcion gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file. As [you can see in the API](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-Loading.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-file) you can use:

```
GdkPixbuf *bmp_pixbuf;
GError *error = NULL;
bmp_pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("/tmp/myfile.bmp", &error);
if (bmp_pixbuf == NULL) {
    /* Error codes are GDK_PIXBUF_ERROR and G_FILE_ERROR */
}
```

It's important to check first the BMP support in GDK using:

```
$ gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders-64 | grep bmp
```

You need a library like libpixbufloader-bmp.so.

I don't know what library are you using to create the 3D scene, but you can get the raw pixels after load the pixbuf with [gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-pixels) and then load into a surface.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

freeimage is the package name which does have method to upload bmp image. From online documentation at freeimage project page I can see the API:

```
DLL_API FIBITMAP *DLL_CALLCONV FreeImage_Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif, const char
*filename, int flags FI_DEFAULT(0));
```

You can

```
yum install freeimage-devel
```

on fedora for development. Use this method and link to the library.

Comment: my bad, I didn't mention that we are forbidden to install any additional libs, the lib must be a pre-built lib in fedora operating system.

Comment: Library is official fedora package. You don't need to build it separately or install it from third party repo. You just need to link it. At development time you will need devel package. That is why I wrote yum command. In short it is part of fedora.

Comment: I seem to maintain this official package for fedora.   https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/freeimage

Answer (score 0):

I'll reuse a previous answer:

[Sean Barrett's stb_image.c](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) is a stand-alone single-file public domain image loader for JPEG, PNG, BMP, TGA, PSD, GIF, HDR and PIC files.